# extracting specific data from JSON format and converting to binomial

Tags: python

i have this JSON format file

```
{'Sensory and Communication': {'Sensory and Communication': {'Visual Impairment': 'Yes', 'Hearing Impairment': 'No', 'Communication': 'No
```

and i wish to extract all the Yes/No and replace them with 1/0 respectively.

this is my current code

```
import json
with open('C:\\Users\Desktop\\IFA.txt') as f:
json_data = json.load(f)

if  json_data['Sensory and Communication']['Visual Impairment']=='Yes':
   ['Sensory and Communication']['Visual Impairment'] == '1'
```

i want to have an IF/ELSE statement so that it is able to read whether it is YES or No and replace them with binomial format

Comment: Binomial? Do you mean Boolean? In Python that's `True` and `False` (they are reserved words, not strings). Aside from that, you have quite a few significant syntax and usage issues here. You should work through some [Python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/) to figure out the basics and then try revisiting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
json_data=dict(json_data)
for k,v in json_data['Sensory and Communication']['Sensory and Communication'].items():
   if v.lower()=='yes':
      json_data['Sensory and Communication']['Sensory and Communication'][k]=1
   else:
      json_data['Sensory and Communication']['Sensory and Communication'][k]=0
```

And then now:

```
print(json_data)
```

Is:

```
{'Sensory and Communication': {'Sensory and Communication': {'Visual Impairment': 1, 'Hearing Impairment': 0, 'Communication': 0}}}
```

As you want binomial format, boolean:

```
json_data=dict(json_data)
for k,v in json_data['Sensory and Communication']['Sensory and Communication'].items():
   if v.lower()=='yes':
      json_data['Sensory and Communication']['Sensory and Communication'][k]=True
   else:
      json_data['Sensory and Communication']['Sensory and Communication'][k]=False
```

And then now:

```
print(json_data)
```

Is:

```
{'Sensory and Communication': {'Sensory and Communication': {'Visual Impairment': True, 'Hearing Impairment': False, 'Communication': False}}}
```

Comment: i get this error 

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @Yuna Now? try it again?

Answer (score 0):

The last line in your code is wrong. instead of '==' you should use '='. '==' is a equal to operation that has boolean output. You can also save the new dict using dump function.

```
if json_data['Sensory and Communication']['Sensory and Communication']['Visual Impairment'] == 'Yes':
    json_data['Sensory and Communication']['Sensory and Communication']['Visual Impairment'] = '1'
    fp = open('C:\\Workspace\\input_new.json','w');
    json.dump(json_data,fp,indent=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet :)

Loop through all vals in the desired location. Supposing they will be either Yes and No — per your file — we replace them with binary boolean vals.

```
LOCATOR = 'Sensory and Communication'

for k,v in json_data[LOCATOR][LOCATOR].iteritems():
    json_data[LOCATOR][LOCATOR][k] = '1' if v == 'Yes' else '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

recursive algorithm would do it for you:

```
def replace_yes_no(data_dict):
    for key, val in data_dict.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            replace_yes_no(val)
        elif isinstance(val, str):
            if val == 'Yes':
                data_dict[key] = 1
            elif val == 'No':
                data_dict[key] = 0
```

output for the input given in the question:

```
{'Sensory and Communication': {'Sensory and Communication': {'Visual Impairment': 1, 'Hearing Impairment': 0, 'Communication': 0}}}
```